# phpBB ip ban does not filter spammers, why?

Tags: phpbb, phpbb3

I have a phpBB forum, and I try to ban some indevidual IP's.
But it doesn't seem to ban them.
Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks,
Meir

Answer (score 0):

They may be using a dynamic IP, in which case you will have to ban their IP range (potentially banning some legitimate users as well).

Comment: Thank you. No. I am talking about permanent IP's. I see them on the ban list, but they still able to post.

Comment: Try also banning the username. It may be that the IP-ban only stops them from logging in.

Comment: That's exactly the reason why you have the IP ban option. They change the user name, but still the same IP.